# What does "Hunch product" mean?

Tags: translation

So I am translating an article and I came upon this paragraph:
"According to the company, the new Sisense Hunch product represents a “new class of big data analytics” that can be applied to applications that were previously impossible on the Internet of Things, due to its latency, power, storage, and cost challenges."
Can somebody please tell me what a Hunch product is? I couldn't really fathom anything when I searched for it.
Thank you.

Comment: As it has an upper case initial and follows the brand name which also has an upper case initial it is obviously the name of a particular product from Sisense. You don't need to translate it any more than you need to translate 'Vantage' when talking about an Aston Martin Vantage. In fact you shouldn't translate it.

Comment: I vote to close because the question is about a trade name and not about meaning or usage.

Comment: Thank you, now that you've mentioned it I see where I've been thinking wrong all along.

Comment: Look up the definition of "hunch".  Apparently it's an AI product and likely involves making conjectures which might be called "hunches".